# how to speed up task performing using snakemake

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, snakemake

```
Machine: 48 cores, 96 threads, RAM 256GB
System: Ubuntu 20.04
Python: 3.9
```

I have a python script for some data processing and analysis and an input dataset containing around 40,000 files for the job.

The script could be run by `python a.py -i sample_list.txt -o /path/to/outdir`.

The `sample_list.txt` contains the file prefixes of all 40000 files in that dataset. Each prefix represented a sample id. In python, it is imported as a `list`. `/path/to/outdir` define the output directory. The software will create a new folder in output directory based on the prefixes first, then the generated data will be put in these new folders sample-by-sample.

I found that this script is analyzing data one by one. I estimated the time, it needs nearly 240 days to finish all the jobs for this dataset! It is unacceptable. I think parallelization for job submission could speed up. That's when snakemake comes into my sight.

I did some study on snakemake. In my case, I can provide three things for snakemake file:

```
input: "sample_list.txt"
output: "/path/to/outdir"
shell: "python a.py -i {input} -o {output}"
```

But I have a question:

If I provided a sample_list file as input, the script will read the file prefix, instead of checking input file pattern e.g. `{input}_1.txt` and import it as input directly. Is it possible to parallelize the jobs based on `sample_list.txt`? Or I must define the input file pattern for `input` of snakemake?

Thanks

**Additional:**

I will print an example for you.

The filename looks like: `sample1_1.fq`, `sample1_2.fq`, `sample2_1.fq`, `sample2_2.fq`, etc.

The software requires a list: `name = ['sample1','sample2','sample3','sample4']`

To get all the sample names (file prefix) I extracted the sample name and stored them in `sample_list.txt`:

```
sample1
sample2
sample3
sample4
```

How to parallelize the jobs?

Edited:

```
def multiprocess(data_path, out_dir, run_name):
  max_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 2
  pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes = max_cores) #, maxtasksperchild = 4
  
  sample_list = []
  for i in os.listdir(data_path):
      #print(i)
      portion = os.path.splitext(i)
      tmp_out = portion[0][0:portion[0].rfind('_')]
      sample_list.append(tmp_out)
  sample_list = sorted(list(set(sample_list)))
  for sample in sample_list:
    pool.apply_async(main, args=(data_path, out_dir, run_name, [sample]))
  print('Wait for all subprocesses done...')
  pool.close()
  pool.join()
  print('All subprocesses done!')
  

if __name__ == '__main__':
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = "Run single sample")
  parser.add_argument('-d','--data',action = 'store', dest = 'data', help = "Data path",required = True)
  parser.add_argument('-o','--outdir',action = 'store', dest = 'outdir', help = "Output directory",required = True)
  parser.add_argument('-r','--runname',action = 'store', dest = 'runname', help = "Define the group",required = True)
  args = parser.parse_args()
  multiprocess(data_path = args.data,out_dir = args.outdir, run_name = args.runname)
```

I loaded 11 samples. It quickly caused RAM leakage. Is there a way to improve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't necessarily need snakemake to achieve a parallelization.
If you wish to use snakemake, you need to define a rule that will process only one sample. The rule you describe will treat all samples at the same time, and thus will be run once without any parallelization.

**The snakemake way:**

```
with open("sample_list.txt", 'r') as f:
    names = f.read().splitlines()

rule all:
    input:  expand("/path/to/outdir/{sample}/{sample}_processedFile.txt",sample=names)

rule process:
    input:  fastq1 = "/path/to/fastq/{sample}_1.fq",
            fastq2 = "/path/to/fastq/{sample}_2.fq"
    output: "/path/to/outdir/{sample}/{sample}_processedFile.txt"
    params: outdir = "/path/to/outdir/{sample}"
    shell:  "python a.py -i {input.fastq1} {input.fastq2} -o {params.outdir}"
```

This assumes:

- your script `a.py` takes as arguments a pair of fastq file, or a sample name if the script knows how to get the fastq files with it.
- your script `a.py` processes only **one** sample at the time.
- all fastq files are located under the same folder.

And you would run snakemake this way:

```
snakemake -j X
```

where X is the number of parallel jobs (do not exceed the number of cores on the machine)

Remember that all python code outside of rules is executed before building the DAG. However, I'm not completely sure snakemake will be able to build its DAG for 40k files...

**The python way:**

You can use the python module **multiprocessing**:

```
import multiprocessing

def processSample(sample):
    # process your sample

# get number of maximum cores on the machine (-1 or more not to overload)
maxCores = multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 1
# build a pool of jobs
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=maxCores)

# add jobs to the pool
for sample in names:
    # process each job
    pool.apply_async(processSample, args=(sample))

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Comment: May I ask another question? I found `multiprocessing` is quite RAM consuming. Setting `maxtasksperchild = 4` in `multiprocessing.Pool` doesn't help decreasing the RAM consuming. Is there a way to limit RAM usage?

Comment: @tomasz It is not multiprocessing which is RAM consuming, it is the process you're using for your samples. multiprocessing just parallelizes your process. If you're running low on RAM, either optimize the memory consumption in your process or lower down the number of task to be performed at the same time. What's in the function `main` your parallelizing?

Comment: You're correct. I have to change `multiprocessing.Pool(processes=maxCores)` to `multiprocessing.Pool(processes=5)` to avoid RAM leakage. But I think there is still some kind of bugs in `multiprocessing`. The script takes two fastqs to STAR for alignment. The largest fastq is only ~400MB, which is quite small. Even if `multiprocessing` import both R1 and R2 fq for 11 samples into the memory, it won't consume hundreds GB of RAM.

Comment: I've tested the whole pipe. The most RAM-consuming step is STAR alignment. I tested five samples, the max RAM usage was 186GB. After STAR alignment finished, it droped quickly to 20~40GB. If I directly send fastq files to STAR. The memory usage is even lower. I can't find much useful information to limit the RAM usage of multiprocessing. I could only reduce the process number, but which will sacrifice the efficiency.

Comment: @tomasz Indeed STAR loads the whole genome index. There are multiple solutions to this. You can either use a smaller reference genome (ie without ALT contigs). In fact ensembl recommends "primary_assembly" instead of "toplevel" for rnaseq data. I do not know what you're doing so it's kind of hard to tell. STAR can also share the genome index between jobs (https://github.com/alexdobin/STAR/blob/master/doc/STARmanual.pdf) (point 3.4). 
Anyway, it looks like you're building an analysis pipeline. Maybe you should ckeck for worflows (https://github.com/nf-core/rnaseq)

Comment: Thanks for your kindly advice. The annotation files are just as you recommended. I've made several changes of parameters and finally found a way to reduce the memory usage of STAR. I called too many threads for STAR. After reducing to half of max cores, nearly 1/4 RAM were saved.